# How to find out if the hard drive replacement is successful?

Tags: drivers, 20.04, hard-drive, ssd

I'm a total newbie, so this might sound stupid. I just replaced the hard drive of an old machine, **LENOVO G510**, with **SSD** and installed **Ubuntu 20.04 LTS** on it. It used to be Windows10 if relevant. How do I check if the replacement is successful? Where should I look?

In solving other problems I noticed that there should be something listed under ***Additional Drivers***, and yet mine was blank. Does it mean my SSD is working? It feels like there're some more steps to take, only I don't know what they are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you installed Ubuntu on the SSD and it booted to Ubuntu without the USB in, then it is replaced successfully.  Additional drivers is not used for hard drives (SSDs).  It is mainly used for video cards and devices where the drivers are proprietary and usually not included with the kernel.

Comment: Thank you! Now I understand a bit how the system works! I'm actually not aware of the option of installing on or not on the SSD; just replaced the disk, inserted USB and followed the tutorial. The machine is restarted properly without the USB in. Does it mean the replacement is fine?

Comment: @PawinData If it restarted without the USB in and came up to the Ubuntu OS, then yes, the replacement is fine.

Comment: Thank you so much!